# html2canvas and jsPDF Safari issue when using morris.js charts to export as PDF do not appear

Tags: javascript

Trying to export a PDF in Safari, the page uses morris.js charts. But when I click export the charts do not appear on the page, however it works on Chrome, Edge and Firefox. I'm not sure why charts are not rendering in Safari or I'm doing something wrong, really appreciate the help.

```
function exportPDF() {
    document.getElementById('navbar').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mainnav-container').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('content-container').style.paddingTop = 0;
    document.getElementById('content-container').style.paddingLeft = 0;
    // html2canvas screenshot
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#capture')).then(canvas => {
        // Set canvas height and width
        var width = canvas.width;
        var height = canvas.height;
        var millimeters = {};
        millimeters.width = Math.floor(width * 0.264583);
        millimeters.height = Math.floor(height * 0.264600);

        // Set chart height and width
        var w = document.getElementById("daily-revenue-chart").offsetWidth;
        var h = document.getElementById("daily-revenue-chart").offsetHeight;

        // Set page dimensions
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                'image/jpeg');
        var doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4", [w, h]);
        doc.deletePage(1);
        doc.addPage(millimeters.width, millimeters.height);
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
        doc.save( '{{ Auth::user()->client_name ?? '' }} Report.pdf');

    })

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: [Safari is the new Internet Explorer](https://dev.to/nektro/safari-is-the-new-internet-explorer-1df0).

Comment: It seems work with other chart plugins, not sure why Safari is so temperamental.